# How can I start swiper with an initial filter?

Tags: search, swiper, ivy

I'd like to start swiper with a filter pre-set on the search -- as if I'd entered a search expression and then used S-SPC (`ivy-restrict-to-matches`) to clear the query space to narrow the results down further.

I can use

```
(swiper "something to search on here")
```

but I still see `something to search on here` in the minibuffer.  How can I get that to go away programmatically?

---

My use-case is a simple way to navigate functions defined in a file. I defined a regexp that matches the beginning of functions up to the function name -- I'd like to match on this name.

Comment: I failed to understand the question. What is the application you have in mind? By the way, by default, `ivy-restrict-to-matches` is bound to `S-SPC`.

Comment: @KaushalModi Whoops, fixed. Thanks. My use-case is a simple way to navigate functions defined in a file. I defined a regexp that matches the beginning of functions up to the function name -- I'd like to match on this name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, since you can't call anything after `read-from-minibuffer` (called by `ivy-read` called by `swiper`) until it returns.
However, there's a visible function `swiper--update-input-ivy` that's called in `post-command-hook`. You can advice this function.
It could also be possible to advice `ivy--exhibit` (it's always in the minibuffer's `post-command-hook`), but `swiper--update-input-ivy` will have less side-effects.

```cl
(defun swiper-ivy-restrict-to-matches-once (&rest r)
  (ivy-restrict-to-matches)
  (advice-remove
   'swiper--update-input-ivy
   'swiper-ivy-restrict-to-matches-once))

(defun swiper-for-defun ()
  (interactive)
  (advice-add
   'swiper--update-input-ivy
   :after 'swiper-ivy-restrict-to-matches-once)
  (swiper "defun"))
```

### New solution due to an update in API

```cl
(defun swiper-for-defun ()
  (interactive)
  (swiper--ivy
   (cl-remove-if-not
    (lambda (x)
      (string-match "^ (defun" x))
    (swiper--candidates))))
```

Comment: Any inhibitions about adding this behavior as an optional argument to `swiper`?

Comment: It could be done. In the source, it would look much more elegant - just a `cl-remove-if-not` over `swiper--candidates`. But why? What's the use case?

Comment: I describe my use case above – that's why I ask. Since this doesn't exist, I'm not convinced I'm taking the right approach.

Comment: That's not a full use case. Surely, you don't `M-:` the piece of code you posted. There's probably some defun and some binding and something you're trying to automate.

Comment: I've edited my comment into the original question. Is that still not a use-case?

Comment: Now it is:)
I would recommend to use `semantic` or `imenu` to navigate tags, but it's your choice. I've updated `swiper--ivy` to suit you more.

Comment: Believe it or not, today I learned about `imenu` (and `counsel-imenu`) :-) Still, +1 to the API change. I think it will prove useful in the future. Thanks for your help!